# usage of spread operator with the store of vuex

Tags: vuex

I begin with Vuex and I follow this example with a [Shopping-cart](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples/shopping-cart).
In the actions of the module cart (store/modules/cart.js), i found this code

```js
// line 30
// actions
const actions = {
  checkout ({ commit, state }, products) {
    const savedCartItems = [...state.items]
    commit('setCheckoutStatus', null)
    // empty cart
    commit('setCartItems', { items: [] })
    shop.buyProducts(
      products,
      () => commit('setCheckoutStatus', 'successful'),
      () => {
        commit('setCheckoutStatus', 'failed')
        // rollback to the cart saved before sending the request
        commit('setCartItems', { items: savedCartItems })
      }
    )
  },
//....
```

`state.items` are the items that I want to checkout.

I'm questionning about `const savedCartItems = [...state.items]`. Is it necessary to use the spread operator ? if i do `const savedCartItems = state.items`, my app seems to be working. Did I miss something ?

Thank you and good day

Answer (score 0):

A difference would be that the use of the spread operator guarantees you

- that you end up with an array (the spread operator doesn't crash in case `items` would be `undefined`.
- that this array is an independent instance

So basically, this creates a shallow copy of your original array, which may be desirable in some cases. Apart from that, there's no crucial difference I'd say.

Comment: but in that specific case (the checkout is failed), I don't understand why it is necessary to use a copy of that array to re-populate the items array. why not the initial state.items.

Comment: @lhapaipai my guess is that vuex arrays are high-level objects that provide state tracking (so `state.items` is not a regular array), and directly using them is discouraged. I'm lacking insights there though, sorry.